# Почему персонаж не прыгает больше 1 раза?

Tags: c#, unity3d

**Вот сам код**

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerCntrl : MonoBehaviour{

private Rigidbody2D rb;

public float speed = 20f;
private float moveInput;
public float jumpForce;


private bool faceRight = true;


private bool isGrounded;
public Transform groundCheck;
public float checkRadius;
public LayerMask whatIsGround;

private int extraJumps;
public int extraJumpsValue;

private void Start(){
    extraJumps = extraJumpsValue;
    rb = GetComponent <Rigidbody2D> ();
}

private void FixedUpdate(){
    isGrounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, checkRadius, whatIsGround);

    moveInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    rb.velocity = new Vector2( moveInput * speed, rb.velocity.y);

    if (faceRight == false && moveInput > 0)
        flip();
    else if (faceRight == true && moveInput < 0)
        flip ();
}

private void Update(){
    if(isGrounded == true){
        extraJumps = extraJumpsValue;
    }
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) && extraJumps > 0){
    rb.velocity = Vector2.up * jumpForce;
    extraJumps--;
    }else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) && extraJumps == 0 && isGrounded == true){
        rb.velocity = Vector2.up * jumpForce;

    }
}

void flip() {
    faceRight = !faceRight;
    transform.localScale = new Vector3 (transform.localScale.x * -1, transform.localScale.y, transform.localScale.z);
}
}
```

Comment: extraJumpsValue откуда берется?

Comment: это действительно вопрос жизни и смерти, раз вы поставили аж 3!!! восклицательных знака?)

Comment: так эту переменную создали в самом юнити и там можно менять

Comment: if(isGrounded == true){
        extraJumps = extraJumpsValue}; типа что бы в коде не менять это значение мы добавляем extraJumpsValue

Comment: Если вписать в Google строчки этого кода, к примеру `isGrounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, checkRadius, whatIsGround);` найдётся сотня тем с этим кодом и одними и теми-же проблемами. Бездумно скопировал класс кода и нет ни малейшего понимания, почему-же он не работает. Я думаю тут сообщество без сильно. Свой код пиши